# How to configure Riak 2 to allow loading of custom erlang modules?

Tags: mapreduce, erlang, config, riak

For 1.x version, this can be done by editing the file 'app.config'.

```
{riak_kv, [
  %% ...
  {add_paths, ["/tmp/beams/"]},
  %% ...
```

But now, 'app.config' has been replaced on 'riak.conf' which has an another format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `/etc/riak/advanced.config` with the following content:

```
[
    {riak_kv, [{add_paths, ["/tmp/beams/"]}]}
].
```

When you start Riak, you'll see messages about cuttlefish merging in the contents of `advanced.config` in the logs (`/var/log/riak/*`).

Answer (score 1):

Last I heard, Joe DeVivo had yet to add support for add_paths to the new configuration format. Certainly as of the Riak 2.0 tech preview it wasn't supported.

However, it is possible to continue to use the old format for configuration bits that are not yet accessible in the new `riak.conf` (Cuttlefish) format, by creating a file named `advanced.config`. See: https://github.com/basho/cuttlefish/issues/13

Comment: I have already read about 'advanced.config', but not understand how I may use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo gvim /var/lib/riak/.erlang

code:add_pathz("/your_erlang_beam_path").
```